# Add Jira WebPart in Sharepoint

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts

On my server, Okta-based authentication is enabled, and I’m using Jira v9.4.11. I want to develop a webpart for my SharePoint website that will function similarly to Jira Legacy in Confluence by filtering issues and adding them to a page. In order to accomplish this, I must authenticate the user in order to call the API from my webpart.

Could someone please assist me with this? When Okta is enabled, how can I authenticate with the Jira server to access data as I can not do this with basic authentication? Also the issues pulled should be specific to the user in SharePoint (Both uses same user and okta logins).

I have tried basic authentication but that is not allowing us to do so due to SSO enabled, and we cant allow basic authentication for APIs as well